# SQL insert ANYDATA object into table - ORA-22370

Tags: sql, oracle, object, plsql

I am trying to insert an ANYDATA type with an object stored inside it into a table column.
I can get it to work fine with Varchars, numbers and dates but not objects. This should be very simple stuff. Here's the code:

```
/*CREATE TYPE SPEC*/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_ot AS OBJECT
(
    some_var       VARCHAR2(50),
    some_clob      CLOB,
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_some_var RETURN VARCHAR2,
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_some_clob RETURN CLOB
);

/*CREATE TYPE BODY*/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY my_ot AS
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_some_var RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN to_char(SELF.some_var);
    END;
    MEMBER FUNCTION get_some_clob RETURN CLOB IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN to_char(SELF.some_clob);
    END;
END;

/*CREATE TABLE*/
create table my_anydata_table ( id NUMBER, mydata sys.anyData );

/*INSERT ANYDATA NUMBER, DATE AND VARCHAR2 WITH NO PROBLEMS*/
insert into my_anydata_table values (1, sys.anyData.convertNumber(100) );
insert into my_anydata_table values (2, sys.anyData.convertDate(sysdate) );
insert into my_anydata_table values (3, sys.anyData.convertVarchar2('SOME TEXT'));
```

All of the code above works fine with no errors.

```
/*INSERT ANYTYPE OBJECT - RETURNS ERROR: ORA-22370*/
insert into my_anydata_table values ( 4, sys.anyData.convertObject(my_ot('input_var', 'input_clob')) );
```

This fails, so I tried it using a PL/SQL BLOCK:

```
/*TRY AGAIN using PL/SQL BLOCK*/
DECLARE
    my_fav_obj my_ot;
    my_anydata sys.anydata;
BEGIN

    my_fav_obj := my_ot('input_var', 'input_clob');
    my_anydata := ANYDATA.ConvertObject(my_fav_obj);
    insert into my_anydata_table values ( 4, my_anydata );

END;
```

This code also fails. I have seen people use this method the same way I did and it seems to work for them. Why is this not working for me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this might an option: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_to_blob_datatype.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here Oracle 11.2 [Anydata type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_anydat.htm#BEHGFEDI):

> Persistent storage of ANYDATA instances whose type contains embedded LOBs other than BFILEs is not currently supported.

So unfortunately you can't store an object type with `LOB` field. I checked your code on SQLFiddle, it worked when I removed the `CLOB` field from the object type.

Comment: Ten years later, this is still a promise of the product documentation and not possible (21c). Inserting an ANYDATA with a clob still throws ORA-22370: incorrect usage of AnyData insert. To me, makes ANYDATA table column data types utterly useless.